# Best way for getting the count of a query set after updating elements

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am looking for the best way to get the size of a query set in rails. However, the elements are updated in a loop and I need the count of the elements before the update. Here is some example (BUGGY !) code.

```
p = participations.where(invited_at: nil).limit(50)
p.each do |participation|
   # Invite may raise an exception, but also contains operations that
   # cannot be undone
   participation.invite()
   participation.invited_at = Time.zone.now
   participation.save
end

DoStuff() if p.count > 0
```

This code does not work, because the call at `p.count` creates a new database query that does not consider the records that have been updated in the loop. Therefore, if there are less than 50 records, they are all updated and `DoStuff()` is not called.

What would be the most idiomatic way in rails to handle this:

1. Move the `if p.count` part out of the loop and only enter the loop if there are any records?
2. Replace `p.count` by `p.size` (if I understand `size` correctly, this should not cause any additional query)
3. Count the number of iterations in the loop and then use that number

I have a feeling that 1 is most idiomatic in ruby, but I don't have much experience in this language.

**EDIT**: Improved example to somewhat closer to the original code.

**EDIT**:

The problem is not about the update queries performed on the participants on the loop. These queries should be individual queries to keep track of which participations have already been handled, even if an error is raised. Rather, the problem is that `DoStuff()` should be called, whenever there have been any records processed in the loop. However, because `count` performs a new query **AFTER** the records have been handled, if there are less than 50 elements to be handled, all will be updated and `DoStuff()` will not be called.

Comment: _However, because count performs a new query AFTER the records have been handled, ..._, so use `size`, no? `p` is already in memory, if nothing changes it's value, then the use of DoStuff shouldn't be affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the difference between `count` - which always execute a query, and `size`, which will return the number of loaded objects, if they are loaded, or will fall back to `count` otherwise. So the easiest fix will be to replace `count` with `size`.

But then `each` returns the collection over which it iterates, so you can do `DoStfuff if p.each(&block).any?` (doesn't look pretty if you have multiline block)

A cleaner way, without having the reviewer to know the difference between `size` and `count`, and without checking if each resulted in a collection with at least one element, is to have your code encapsulated in a method and add a guard clause.

```
def process_invitations
  p = participations.where(invited_at: nil).limit(50)
  return if p.none?

  p.each do |participation|
   # Invite may raise an exception, but also contains operations that
   # cannot be undone
   participation.invite()
   participation.invited_at = Time.zone.now
   participation.save
  end

  DoStuff()
end
```

You can even remove the limit and use `p.first(50).each do`

Answer (score 0):

> Move the if p.count part out of the loop and only enter the loop if there are any records?

`.each` does not enter the loop if there are no records. If you want proof try:

```
MyModel.none.each { puts "Hello world" }
```

If you want a more idiomatic way then don't use `#each` if you care about the results. `#each` should only be used when you only care about the side effects of the iteration.

Instead use `#map` or one of the many other iteration methods.

```
def process_invitations
  p = participations.where(invited_at: nil).limit(50)
  p.map do |participation|
   # Invite may raise an exception, but also contains operations that
   # cannot be undone
   participation.invite()
   participation.invited_at = Time.zone.now
   participation.save
  end.reject.yeild_self do |updates|
    # run do_stuff if any of the records where updated
    do_stuff() if updates.any?
  end
end
```

Or if you for example only wanted to `do_stuff` to records that where updated:

```
def process_invitations
  p = participations.where(invited_at: nil).limit(50)
  p.map do |participation|
   # Invite may raise an exception, but also contains operations that
   # cannot be undone
   participation.invite()
   participation.invited_at = Time.zone.now
   participation if participation.save
  end.reject.yeild_self do |updated|
    do_stuff(updated) if updated.any?
  end
end
```

Or `do_stuff` to each of the records that where updated:

```
def process_invitations
  p = participations.where(invited_at: nil).limit(50)
  p.map do |participation|
   # Invite may raise an exception, but also contains operations that
   # cannot be undone
   participation.invite()
   participation.invited_at = Time.zone.now
   participation if participation.save
  end.reject.map do |record|
    do_stuff(record)
  end
end
```